# Slick fade div disappears

Tags: html, css, slick.js

I need a fade in fade out carousel and I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="flash-container">
  <div class="documentsItem">
    <a href="" id="lnkDocuments">
      <div class="itemtitle" id="divTitle">Title 1</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="documentsItem">
    <a href="" id="lnkDocuments">
      <div class="itemtitle" id="divTitle"> Title 2</div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="documentsItem">
    <a href="" id="lnkDocuments">
      <div class="itemtitle" id="divTitle"> Title 3</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flash-container{
    float:right;
    width:555px;
}
.documentsItem 
{
    float:right;
     width:800px;
}
.documentsItem a{
    width:100%;
    float:right;
}
.allitemslink{
    float:right;
}
.slider-parent-doc{
    width:100%;
     float:right;
}

.slick-list {
    margin-top:25px;
    border:solid 1px;
}

.documentsItem a img
{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    float:right;
}
.documentsItem a .itemtitle{
    float:right;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('.flash-container').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 1000,
  fade: true,
  infinite: true
});
```

When this code runs it only shows the *Title2* with fade in fade out effect. The other element are not showing at all. I need to show all the `div`'s like in a carousel. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem is

```
float: right;
```

After removing this from the css the fade works properly. Question can be closed